# Replace autoload with spl_autoload_register

Tags: php

Fatal error: __autoload() is no longer supported, use spl_autoload_register() instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\php1\FORUM4\core\init.php on line 14

here is code:

```
 ....//Autoload Classes
function __autoload($class_name){
    require_once('libraries/'.$class_name.'.php');
}.....
```

Question: how i replace with spl_autoload_register() ?

Comment: The doc page for this function explains exactly how to do that.

Comment: https://www.php.net/spl_autoload_register